# Specify dynamic rows for Index formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number of datasets on a sheet that calculate monthly and annual staff hires and terminations. I have another dataset to calculate the annual running staffing totals for specific disciplines by subtracting one specific row from another. The funcion I use is:

```
=LET(duration, SEQUENCE(1,(StudioProjectedOperatingMonths+12)/12, COLUMN(K:K)),
StartRow, 25,
RowsUntilSecondRow, 44,
DisciplineEntryIndex, ROW(INDEX(DisciplineTbl[Discipline],MATCH(J113,DisciplineTbl[Discipline],0)))-ROW(DisciplineTbl[#Headers])-1,
FirstRow, StartRow+DisciplineEntryIndex,
SecondRow, StartRow+RowsUntilSecondRow+DisciplineEntryIndex,
DisciplineValues, INDEX($1:$84,{25;69},duration),
StaffInOut, LET(x, DisciplineValues,INDEX(x,1)-INDEX(x,2)),
SCAN(0, StaffInOut,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))
)
```

This gives the correct result when inserted in to K113 (highlighted cell below):

[image]

However, when I drag copy the formula from K113 to K114 etc I have to adjust the row references in the Index function to be `INDEX($1:$84,{26;70},duration)` and so on.

To try and get around this, I created the variables **FirstRow** and **SecondRow** which start off at 25 and 69 as per the Index part of the full formula above, and use the indexed row of the discipline in the discipline table to add a value. For example, if the Discipline is Programming it will add 0, if Design it will add 1 etc.

My thinking was to replace the `INDEX($1:$84,{25;69},duration)` part of the formula with `INDEX($1:$84,{FirstRow;SecondRow},duration)` but unfortunately it doesn't like this syntax.

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to approach it differently?

Comment: `INDEX($1:$84,VSTACK(FirstRow;SecondRow)`

Comment: This still gives me the "There is a problem with this formula"  "Not trying to type a formula" error. I used `DisciplineValues, INDEX($1:$84,VSTACK(FirstRow;SecondRow),duration) `

Comment: sorry the `;` should be a `,`

Comment: Just noticed, changed and gives a nice solution, thanks